# Easiest way to convert existing table to Laravel table schema

Tags: php, laravel

I already have existing tables in the database.

Is there any package that can convert an existing table to an equivalent Laravel's table migrations?

Comment: https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Laravel online migration generator.
Try: https://laravelarticle.com/laravel-migration-generator-online
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this floating about - haven't had a chance to test it myself but comes quite highly recommended:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-migration-generator

FYI : Designed for Laravel4